# Cleaning a list of data in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

For cleaning a list of data, I have created a method which accepts the list of data and list of cleaning operation to be performed.

```
public <T> List<T> cleanData(List<T> data, List<Function<T, T>> cleanOps) {
    List<T>dataNew=data.stream().map((str) -> {
        T cleanData = str;
        for(Function<T,T> function:cleanOps) {
            cleanData=function.apply(cleanData);
        }
        return cleanData;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return dataNew;
}
```

The issue here is that we are creating the whole list again as `Collectors.toList()` returns a new list.
Can we achieve the same result without using the extra space?

Below is the code for invocation:

```
public void processData() {
    List<Function<String, String>> cleanOps = new ArrayList<>();
    cleanOps.add(String::toLowerCase);
    cleanOps.add(str -> str.replaceAll(" ", ""));
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add("John Doe");
    data.add("Jane Doe");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cleanData(data, cleanOps).toArray()));
}
```

Comment: `toList()` returns a `Collector` not  a `List`, and no: you cannot have "extra data" without "extra space"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If modifying the list in-place is allowed, you could use

```
public <T> List<T> cleanData(List<T> data, List<Function<T, T>> cleanOps) {
    cleanOps.stream().reduce(Function::andThen).ifPresent(f -> data.replaceAll(f::apply));
    return data;
}
```

`andThen` combines two `Function` instances and if at least one function was present, i.e. the `cleanOps` list is not empty, the resulting combined function will be applied to all list elements and the elements replaced by the result, using `replaceAll`.

Unfortunately, `replaceAll` requires a `UnaryOperator<T>` rather than a `Function<T,T>`, despite being functionally equivalent, so we have to use the adapter `f::apply`.

Since these function types are equivalent, we could change the list to `List<UnaryOperator<T>>`, but then, we have to face the fact that there is no specialized `andThen` implementation for `UnaryOperator`, so we would need:

```
public <T> List<T> cleanData(List<T> data, List<UnaryOperator<T>> cleanOps) {
    cleanOps.stream()
        .reduce((f1,f2) -> t -> f2.apply(f1.apply(t)))
        .ifPresent(data::replaceAll);
    return data;
}
```

The caller’s source changes to

```
List<UnaryOperator<String>> cleanOps = new ArrayList<>();
cleanOps.add(String::toLowerCase);
cleanOps.add(str -> str.replaceAll(" ", ""));
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add("John Doe");
data.add("Jane Doe");
System.out.println(cleanData(data, cleanOps));
```

then.

As a side note, there is no need for a construct like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cleanData(data, cleanOps).toArray()));
```

as the `toString()` method of a `List` produces exactly the same output. Since the `println(Object)` method calls `toString()` implicitly, you can just use

```
System.out.println(cleanData(data, cleanOps));
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you need to use `List.replaceAll()`, which replaces each element of this list with the result of applying the given operator to that element.

```
public <T> List<T> cleanString(List<T> data, List<Function<T, T>> cleanOps) {
    data.replaceAll(str -> {
        T cleanData = str;
        for (Function<T,T> function : cleanOps) {
            cleanData = function.apply(cleanData);
        }
        return cleanData;
    });
    return data;
}
```

I'd rename the method, though, since it's generic, so it doesn't necessarily process a `List` of `String`s.